# Amcharts: how use csv files with factors?

Tags: csv, amcharts

Is it possible to use draw several lines depending on the factor column? I'll explain. I have next csv files:

```
year,lessThanWorkingAge,withinWorkingAge,moreThanWorkingAge,sex
2004,203,4928,32143,female
2005,195,4728,32005,female
2006,155,4211,31578,female
2007,150,3997,30526,female
2008,151,3800,30930,female
2009,180,3544,30614,female
2010,194,3411,31236,female
2011,171,3294,29193,female
2012,181,3243,29913,female
2013,187,2992,29505,female
2004,298,17634,19317,male
2005,252,17070,19120,male
2006,223,15264,18594,male
2007,179,14023,18591,male
2008,206,13153,18469,male
2009,230,11998,18341,male
2010,238,11449,18867,male
2011,221,11043,17810,male
2012,242,10485,17961,male
2013,232,9879,17509,male
```

How can i draw two lines for `female` and `male` usnig `sex` column as factor, `year` as x axis category and `lessThanWorkingAge` as y axis value?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, amCharts does not support data like this.

However, if you are using [Data Loader](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader) to load the CSV data to the chart, you can use its `postProcess` handler to automatically reformat the data so same-category values are consolidated into the same data point, so it does work.

Something like this:

```
"dataLoader": {
  "url": "data.csv",
  "format": "csv",
  "useColumnNames": true,
  "postProcess": function(data) {
    var tmp = {};
    var newData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = data[i];
      if (tmp[row.year] === undefined)
        tmp[row.year] = {
          "year": row.year
        };
      tmp[row.year][row.sex] = row.lessThanWorkingAge;
    }
    for (var x in tmp) {
      if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(x))
        newData.push(tmp[x]);
    }
    return newData;
  }
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/dcce3ec3c125465bf08a817b17c91e8a) of the chart that loads your data using Data Loader.